# dask distributed - right way to use list returned from a delayed function

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

My question may be dumb but I just started learning dask distrubuted. Any help is appreciated.

I have code like below:

```py
    @dask.delayed
    def do_something(date):
        return x, y
    
    get_item0 = dask.delayed(operator.itemgetter(0))
    get_item1 = dask.delayed(operator.itemgetter(1))

    def handle_x(list_x):
        # do something
        print(len(list_x))

    def handle_y(list_y):
        # do something
        print(len(list_y))
    
    def do_tasks():
        list_x, list_y = [], []
        dates = [20210101, 20210102, 20210103, 20210104, 20210105]
        for date in dates:
            result = do_something(date)
            x = get_item0(result)
            y = get_item1(result)
            list_x.append(x)
            list_y.append(y)
        return list_x, list_y
    
    with dask.Distributed.Client(cluster) as dask_client:
        tasks = do_tasks()
        list_x = get_item0(tasks)
        list_y = get_item1(tasks)
    
        # I want to print 5, which is number of dates, but this prints 2
        print(len(tasks))

        # I want to pass list_x and list_y to handle_x and handle_y separately. But the following code computes do_tasks twice. How do I fix that?
        dask_client.compute(dask.lazy(handle_x)(list_x)).result()
        dask_client.compute(dask.lazy(handle_y)(list_y)).result()
```

1. How can I print out 5 (number of dates)? `print(len(tasks))` seems to print 2 (which is length of `list_x, list_y`) instead of 5
2. I want to pass list_x and list_y to handle_x and handle_y separately. But my code computes `do_tasks` twice.

How do I fix them?

Answer (score 2):

A minor thing, but you can use `nout` to delayed if you know the number of returned items:

```py
@dask.delayed(nout=2)
def do_something(date):
    return x, y

# simplifies a bit this function
def do_tasks():
    list_x, list_y = [], []
    dates = [20210101, 20210102, 20210103, 20210104, 20210105]
    for date in dates:
        x, y = do_something(date)
        list_x.append(x)
        list_y.append(y)
    return list_x, list_y
```

Specifically about your questions:

1. This should print 5, the previuos code was referring to `result` which contained 2 lists.

```py
# note, using dask.client is not necessary at this stage
# everything is still delayed
list_x, list_y = do_tasks()

# this will print 5
print(len(list_x))
```

2. To compute both objects at the same time, it's best to let `dask` know about the links in the computation graph by submitting both computations at the same time:

```py
with dask.Distributed.Client(cluster) as dask_client:

    # note that for simplicity handle_x/y are used without passing
    # them through decoration, but they can be delayed functions
    result = dask_client.compute([handle_x(list_x), handle_y(list_y)])
```